# Check user input in C with scanf()

Tags: c, if-statement, input

Purpose:

If user input `b` is a `float` number prints `floor(b), round(b), ceil(b)`.

Else prints `scanf error: (%d)\n`.

The instruction (provided by our teacher) has a code like this, which I don't understand. [image]

Here's my code:
`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float b;
    printf("Eneter a float number");
    int a=0;
    a=5;
    a=scanf("%d", &b);
    if (a=0)
    {
        printf("scanf error: (%d)\n",a);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%g %g %g",floor(b), round(b), ceil(b));
    }
    return 0
}
```

Comment: perhaps reading this may help - [man scanf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/scanf)

Comment: You can't use "%d" for a float.

Comment: @EdHeal: Also compiling with `-Wall` (or equivalent, depending on compiler). GCC `-Wall` would've picked up both the `a=0` and the `%d` errors.

Comment: "The instruction (provided by our teacher) has a code like this, which I don't understand. " --> Ask the teacher.  Else you don't have a "teacher".

Comment: @stark Of course you can, but is wrong :))

Comment: Also, please fix the spelling of `Enter`

Comment: it's like a lab.. we just read what's been provided.

Comment: @RuiYu - The idea is also to learn the ability to look for information from other sources. You are fortunate you have google etc. It is wise to look up and read the manual pages of functions that you are using . Today - Please read the manual page for `scanf`. Then read `printf`. It will aid you understanding. PS: When I was a student we did not have the internet nor the web - yes I am ancient

Answer (score 4):

**Mistake # 1**

```
if (a=0)  // condition will be always FALSE
```

must be

```
if (a==0)
```

or better

```
if (0 == a)
```

**Mistake # 2**

```
scanf("%d", &b); // when b is float
```

instead of

```
scanf("%f", &b);
```

**UPDATE:**

Actually, for case of checking results of `scanf` I personally prefer to use `!=` with number of values entered with the last `scanf`. E.g. if two comma separated integers required to continue calculation snippet can be:

```
int x, y;
int check;
do{
    printf("Enter x,y:");
    check = scanf("%d,%d", &x, &y); // enter format is x,y
    while(getchar()!='\n'); // clean the input buffer
}while(check != 2);
```

that loop will re-ask for input if `check` is not `2`, i.e. if it is `0` (when even the first value is incorrect, e.g. `abc,12`) or if it is `1` (when user forgot comma or enter not a number after comma, e.g. `12,y`

Comment: Yoda is not better (modern compilers can pick this problem up)

Comment: @EdHeal you have proven his teacher is stupid on the basis of standards but he is not coz he use compilers and not just read those standards .

Comment: Why is `0 == a` better than `a==0`?

Comment: `0 == a` better than `a==0` because compiler find error `0=a` at compile time, but think that `a=0` is correct when you make a mistake in `a==0`

Answer (score 1):

Code with corrections and comments - also available here - http://ideone.com/eqzRQe

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void) {
    float b;
//    printf("Eneter a float number");
    printf("Enter a float number"); // Corrected typo
    fflush(stdout); // Send the buffer to the console so the user can see it
    int a=0;
//    a=5; -- Not required
    a=scanf("%f", &b); // See the manual page for reading floats
    if (a==0) // Need comparison operator not assignemnt
    {
        printf("scanf error: (%d)\n",a); // A better error message could be placed here
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%g\n", b); // Just to check the input with ideone - debugging
        printf("%g %g %g",floor(b), round(b), ceil(b));
    }
    return 0; // You need the semi-colon here
}
```

For VenuKant Sahu benefit

> Return Value
>
> These functions return the number of input items successfully matched
>   and assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero in
>   the event of an early matching failure.
>
> The value EOF is returned if the end of input is reached before either
>   the first successful conversion or a matching failure occurs. EOF is
>   also returned if a read error occurs, in which case the error
>   indicator for the stream (see ferror(3)) is set, and errno is set
>   indicate the error.

Comment: Please tell me if I'm right. `scanf("%f", &b)` is a function, after it runs it returns 1 or 0, 1 means it runs, 0 means it does not. Can I consider it as a Boolean value then?